# Json Array Elements to html page

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm new to using JSON and I'm trying to do something that I'm convinced is very simple but I've been looking for a while and haven't yet found the right way to do it.
I have two files, a html page and a json file with an array inside it.
The contents of the JSON file looks like this:

```
[
{ "name": "EXAMPLE1",
      "description": "this is a sample description"},
{ "name": "EXAMPLE2",
  "description": "This is a second sample description"}
]
```

What I'm trying to do fetch the array elements and display them on the html page with "name" being a heading (h1) and "description" being a paragraph (p).

Below is the code I have so far in my html file and I wouldn't be surprised if I've totally misunderstood how to go about this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Json Arrays</title>  
    </head>

    <body>


    </body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON("testarray.json", function(data){
$.each(data, function)(){
$("body").append("<h1>"+this['name']+<br>"</h1>""<p>"+this['description']+<br>"</p>");
}
}
}
        </script>
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You will need a server to serve the json. You can set up a server on your machine which returns the json file and then this would work. You can also look into this if you don't want to set up your server: http://www.jsontest.com

Answer (score 1):

You got to parse it properly. Here is the code I tweaked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Json Arrays</title>  
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>


    </body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $.getJSON("testarray.json", function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function(i, field){

                    $("body").append("<h1>"+field.name+"<br></h1><p>"+field.description+"<br></p>");
                    });

            })
        });
        </script>
</html>
```

after each each and everything will be object so just use `field.name`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "and everything will be object so just use field.name"

Comment: You tired to get the value object as array.. instead get the object and it's property

Comment: I'm still not getting any output on the page? Just checking but appending on body should work right?

Comment: List of steps you got to follow. 1) Are you trying to do this in any kind of server MAMP, LAMP, XAMPP? 2) create `.json` and paste the JSON. 3)Copy paste the html 4) Run via localhost. still getting error check the console find what error you are facing